# CGPathRef encoding

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nscoding

Is it possible to encode CGPathRef variables? I mean is there an encodeObject:forKey like method for CGPathRef variables?

Answer (score 2):

yes, there is - I have done this: https://github.com/mro/MROGeometry/blob/master/NSCoder_MROCGPath.m

Comment: Oh no, the only link that was about to save my life is broken now.

Comment: here it is: https://github.com/mro/MROGeometry/blob/master/MROGeometry/NSCoder_MROCGPath.m

Comment: It seems as though it won't handle all paths yet? There's a comment that it doesn't support "eliptical arcs".

Comment: Also, the license is fairly political.

Answer (score 1):

CGPaths are objects, but I don't think you can encode them—at least, if you can, it's not documented. You'll need to generate a saveable representation of the path yourself, and encode that, and then, when you decode that representation, reincarnate the path from it yourself.

Comment: Is there any relationship between `CGPathRef` and `NSBezierPath`? `NSBezierPath` should be serializable, and if there's a way to convert one to the other, you could encode the `NSBezierPath` and convert to a CGPath as needed. `NSBezierPath` strikes me as a bit less opaque than CGPath.

Comment: No, there is none. You would have to convert manually using an applier function. This is usually not that hard, but if the CGPath contains a quadratic curve (one with one control point), you'd have to convert that to a cubic curve (two control points).

Comment: On iOS, you can `UIBezierPath`, which is `NSCoding` compliant and which implements a class method `bezierPathWithCGPath:`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9938864/encode-and-decode-cgmutablepathref-with-arc/23548794#23548794

Answer (score 1):

This [header](https://github.com/GenerallyHelpfulSoftware/SVGgh/blob/master/SVGgh/SVGRenderer/SVGPathGenerator.h) on Github has two utility strings to interchange CGPaths with NSStrings:

```
+(nullable NSString*) svgPathFromCGPath:(CGPathRef)aPath;
+(nullable CGPathRef) newCGPathFromSVGPath:(NSString*)anSVGPath whileApplyingTransform:(CGAffineTransform)aTransform;
```

You can use those strings with NSCoders to store things away. Be warned that anytime you convert between paths and strings you might lose significant digits because of the conversion.

I wrote these routines and they are under MIT license.