# Encode and Decode CGMutablePathRef with ARC

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, nscoding, cgpath

Under ARC, is it possible to encode/decode a `CGMutablePathRef` (or its non-mutable form) using `NSCoding`? Naively I try:

```
path = CGPathCreateMutable();
...
[aCoder encodeObject:path]
```

but I get a friendly error from the compiler:

```
Automatic Reference Counting Issue: Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'CGMutablePathRef' (aka 'struct CGPath *') is disallowed with ARC
```

What can I do to encode this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [CGPathRef encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429426/cgpathref-encoding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSCoding` is a protocol. Its methods can only be used with objects that conform to the `NSCoding` protocol. a `CGPathRef` isn't even an object, so `NSCoding` methods won't work directly. That's why you're getting that error.

[Here's a guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5784668/689356) who has come up with a way to serialize CGPaths.

Comment: I went ahead and changed over to using `UIBezierPath` although I could have wrapped the CGPath using one of the `UIBezierPath` class methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not due to ARC, but to the mismatch between Core Graphics code based in C and the NSCoding mechanism based in Objective-C.

To use encoders/decoders, you need to use objects that conform to the Objective-C `NSCoding` protocol. `CGMutablePathRef` does not conform since it is not an Objective-C object but a Core Graphics object reference.

However, `UIBezierPath` is an Objective-C wrapper for a CGPath and it does conform.

You can do the following:

```
CGMutablePathRef mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
// ... you own mutablePath. mutate it here...
CGPathRef persistentPath = CGPathCreateCopy(mutablePath);
UIBezierPath * bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:persistentPath];
CGPathRelease(persistentPath);
[aCoder encodeObject:bezierPath];
```

and then to decode:

```
UIBezierPath * bezierPath = [aCoder decodeObject];
if (!bezierPath) { 
  // workaround an issue, where empty paths decode as nil
  bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath]; 
}
CGPathRef  path = [bezierPath CGPath];
CGMutablePathRef * mutablePath = CGPathCreateMutableCopy(path);
// ... you own mutablePath. mutate it here
```

This works in my tests.

Answer (score 0):

If you asking for storing CGPath persistently you should you use the CGPathApply function. Check [here](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=1312) for how to do that.